# How do i deploy a contract on chain using bytecode

Tags: contract-deployment, bytecode, smart-contract

I'd like to deploy a smart contract that can take in bytecode as the argument and deploy that contract. Currently, the only way I see examples of is that they take a specific contract that is already on chain. Can anyone point me to how we deploy on-chain from a bytecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to write a Solidity smart contract that takes a creation bytecode as input and then deploys a child smart contract using that creation bytecode via `CREATE1` or `CREATE2`. For the sake of demonstration, I will show you how to do so via `CREATE1`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract DeployBytecode {
    function deployFromBytecode(bytes memory bytecode) public returns (address) {
        address child;
        assembly{
            mstore(0x0, bytecode)
            child := create(0,0xa0, calldatasize())
        }
        return child;
   }
}
```

The creation bytecode is what people usually refer to when they say "bytecode". You could fetch the creation bytecode from an already-deployed smart contract using Etherscan and going to the #code section of a smart contract and then scrolling down to "Contract Creation Code". It can also be retrieved onchain in Solidity via: `type(ContractName).creationCode`. Alternatively, you could generate the bytecode locally by running the compilation script in your local Hardhat or Foundry project. The bytecode can usually be found in the JSON compiler output (e.g., `./artifacts/.../YourContract.json`).

Once the smart contract is deployed, a modified version of the bytecode is stored onchain known as the runtime bytecode or deployed bytecode. It differs from the creation bytecode, as it does not contain the constructor logic or constructor parameters. The runtime bytecode of a smart contract can be retreived onchain in Solidity via: `type(ContractName).runtimeCode`. Note that you cannot deploy a smart contract by copying the runtime bytecode, since it is only meant for describing the functions and logic a smart contract contains after it is deployed.

Comment: Thank you for this and for including the example - will give this a try!

Comment: I've now tried to actually deploy it onchain. It doesn't seem to work as intended - the return address is zero. And example of the failed transaction: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x144e050e21873b5e13f9e5f33859f3361687f2704893144738f680937d364d71

Comment: There is something wrong with the bytecode you're providing as input. It's not working for me neither. I'm guessing it's most-likely due to an error in the provided bytecode's constructor code. You could try another bytecode to test that this works.

Comment: Scroll down to the bytecode of this deployed contract and use it for testing:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302#code

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - i think the issue was that Metamask can't estimate the correct gas for a contract deployment this way, so the function calls have been running out of gas. Manually specifying the gas has ensured that the contract gets deployed successfully. I'm having issues verifying the contract on Etherscan from the original Solidity contract but at this point, I'd consider this answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have creation code . You can send a transaction to 0 address with the hex data filed with the creation code of the contract .

Please note there are two types of bytecodes:-

Creation code(or init code) and runtime code.